# why is there the error `Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL` on merge command sometimes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I use `merge` statement for inserting new data or deleting data. I use a `temp table` as `source` and a table as `target`.

the target table has a `foreign ke`y with another table(`Table A`).

I encounter following error sometimes when (`when matched then delete` statement) is executed.

```
error:
    Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL.
```

If I comment this line the query is run perfectly.

also If i remove the `foreign key` between `Material table` and `table A` query is run perfectly too.

I have applied this [Hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2671078) but I have mentioned problem yet.

SQL Server version:`Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)`

```
**Target Tbale (Material)**                **Table A**

PatientIdRef (ForeignKey)             PatientId(Primary Key)
VisitNumberRef(Foreign Key)           VisitNumber(Primary Key)
Unit_Price                            Name
Unit_Price_Ins                        family
....
....                            

create tabl #Temp 
(
  patinetId [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
  [Visit_Number] [smallint] NULL,
  [Unit_Price] [float] NULL,
  [Unit_Price_Ins] [float] NULL,
  ......
  .....
)
merge materials as target
using(select patinetId ,Visit_Number,Unit_Price,Unit_Price_Ins
from #Temp
) as source
on (source.patientid=target.patientid collate arabic_ci_as and source.visit_number=target.visit_number)
when matched then delete
when not matched then insert
(patinetIdref ,Visit_Numberref,Unit_Price,Unit_Price_Ins )
values(patinetId ,Visit_Number,Unit_Price,Unit_Price_Ins)
```

Comment: Can you show us definition of the `foreign key`?

Comment: `PatientId` is patient `File Number` and VisitNumber is `visit time`.
`Table A` is Patient spcifications and `Material table` is the materials that patient is used. one patient(PatientId,VisitNumber) can have multiple materials.

Comment: By definition i meant sql that creates it. Btw in your whole post there is no `File number` nor `Visit Time`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE [HIS_FinArchives].[Materials]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Materials_Patients] FOREIGN KEY([Patient_ID_I], [Visit_Number])
REFERENCES [HIS_FinArchives].[Patients] ([Patient_ID_I], [Visit_Number])`
TableA=His_FinArchives.patients,
Material=His_Finarchives.Materials

Comment: Is VisitNumberRef NOT NULL? I guess so since it references "Table A" VisitNumber which is PK and must be NOT NULL. #Temp.Visit_Number is can be NULL however. Does `SELECT * from #Temp where Visit_Number IS NULL` return any records?

Comment: `VisitNumberRef` is not null and `visit_Number` is not null too.
I cheked #temp for `NULL` values but I don't  have any null values.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are experiencing this problem in a case where the target table has more than one foreign key (FK) constraint, it's most probably due to this bug: [FIX: "Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL" error message when you use a MERGE statement in SQL Server 2008, in SQL Server 2008 R2 or in SQL Server 2012](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2671078)

You are running SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 version 10.50.2550

This is fixed in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 version 10.50.2822 and later (Cumulative Update 8).

Download from here: [Cumulative update package 8 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2723743)

Or preferably, download the latest Cumulative Update available for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1: [Cumulative update package 13 for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2855792)

---

You mention that you have already applied one of the SQL Server hotfixes for this, but I suggest you double check that it is installed properly by executing `SELECT @@VERSION` and verifying that the version number is 10.50.2822 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following:

- Error message that you cannot set a NON-NULLABLE value to NULL
- Applied suggested hotfix did not address your issue
- Your `MERGE` statement works without the `when matched then delete` or without the foreign key constraint

I suspect the issue is with a foreign key constraint pointing to your `Materials` table configured to `ON DELETE SET NULL`. You can verify if there are any foreign keys pointing to `Materials` with `EXEC sp_fkeys 'Materials'`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "fix" this error by moving the select out of the using statement and put it in a temporary table.

That is, I change this:

```
 MERGE dbo.IVS_LIVE t
            USING (SELECT PolicyNumber
                         ,EffectiveDate
                         ,cast(null as date) as TerminationDate
                         ,CAST('CRS' as CHAR(4)) as datasource
                         ,VIN
                         ,State 
                         ,IVS_RUNHISTORY_ID
                     FROM dbo.IVS_CRS_STAGING
                    WHERE PolicyStatus in (10, 60, 70)
                       OR (    PolicyStatus not in (10, 60, 70, 99)
                           AND PolicyStatusDate >= (select irh.RunDate
                                                      from dbo.IVS_RUNHISTORY irh
                                                     where irh.ID = @ivs_runhistory_id
                                                   )
                          )
                  ) as s
```

to this:

```
MERGE dbo.IVS_LIVE t
            USING #sourcetbl as s
```

I would guess that the simpler code did not trigger this bug in the very old version of sql server I am forced to use:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/981037/fix-attempting-to-set-a-non-null-able-column-s-value-to-null-error-mes