# Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm experiencing a strange issue on a clients database when using the `ISNULL()` function of SQL Server 2014. Searching online has lead me to other people experiencing the same error but when `INSERT`ing. I'm getting the following error when running a simple `SELECT`:

```
Msg 681, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL.
```

The following query produces that error:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL( [t2].[date_update], GETDATE() )
FROM
    [dbo].[t1]
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[t2] ON [t1].[a] = [t2].[id];
```

I've stripped down the tables to simplify my explanation, but the affected columns are defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1] (
    [id]          INT           NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [a]           NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t2] (
    [id]          BIGINT        NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [date_update] DATETIME      NULL
);
```

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Edit:

In troubleshooting I was able to reproduce the same error message on the clients system with the following `INSERT`:

```
CREATE TABLE #t2 ([id] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED, [date_update] DATETIME NULL);

INSERT INTO #t2 ([id], [date_update)
SELECT [id], [date_update]
FROM [dbo].[t2];
```

Edit2:

More troubleshooting has indicated that the index the `SELECT` is using is at fault. When trying to rebuild the index I get the same error!

```
Rebuild failed for Index xxx
Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL.
```

Comment: You're joining a BIGINT column to an NVARCHAR(100) column?

Comment: The only thing that I can see is that you are comparing a text based field with an integer type. Perhaps the error message is just wrong. Are you sure that every instance of [a] can be converted to a BIGINT? SELECT [a] FROM [dbo].[t1] WHERE TRY_PARSE([a] AS BIGINT) IS NULL

Comment: Yes I thought the same, but this isn't the cause of the issue. All values in the NVARCHAR column can be implicitly converted to BIGINTs.

Comment: Using your stripped down tables, what data can you put in those tables that will cause this error to reproduce?   I suspect the error is caused by some part of the code you have stripped out.

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce the error locally on my laptop but I'm unable to do so given any combination of data. I suspect it's an environment issue.

Comment: I was just able to reproduce the error on the clients server in an alternative method - I will update the question.

Comment: It could be environmental if you are doing an insert or update in any part of the code you have stripped out, but a SELECT can never try to set the value of a column in any environment that I'm aware of.

Comment: check the answer here:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955418/why-is-there-the-error-attempting-to-set-a-non-null-able-columns-value-to-null?rq=1

Comment: @lad2025 - The question clearly states SELECT.

Comment: @TabAlleman - Thanks but it's running SQL 2014 (12.0.2000.8) - Presuming all 2012 hotfixes would have been included in 2014.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com I can't recreate your case

Comment: I don't see a programming error here.   If this is an environmental issue, you'd be more likely to get help with it on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is the error replicated when using `COALESCE()` instead of `ISNULL()`?

Comment: @TabAlleman I think you're right, see edit2 above, I think there may be corruption within one or more of the indexes.

Comment: Can you drop and re-create the index?

Comment: @TabAlleman Unfortunately it's the clustered index that is corrupted, somehow there exists a row containing nothing but NULLs, including in the NOT NULL columns. I suspect a disk error may have caused this or maybe corruption in backup transport. I'll be notifying the client that they have corruption in their database and back away slowly :)

Comment: Anyone who found this while searching for the error text may be interested in a link explaining why this error can show up when merging data into a system-versioned temporal table that has a nonclustered index on the history table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734060/why-does-a-merge-into-a-temporal-table-with-a-nonclustered-index-in-the-history

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message was being displayed due to the existence of a completely NULL row in a table containing NOT NULL column definitions.

The cause of the corruption is unknown in this case but the error can be explained where the `SELECT` query is creating a hash table in order to facilitate the join, it's trying to insert NULL into the primary key column.

This can be tested for by creating a table with the same definition but with all columns `NULL`able, inserting into it from the corrupted table, then querying for `NULL`s in the supposed `NOT NULL` columns.

Answer (score -1):

sometimes when I call
`select * from sys.dm_exec_query_stats`
I get this error and I have no idea how to catch it. `TRY` `CATCH` doesn't catch this error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This does not anwer the question. Consider opening a new question if you have a problem.To improve your answers, please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).